# Does PDF support having a "hidden" HTML file for automatically reading the content?

Tags: html, pdf

PDF is nice for viewing as it looks everywhere the same (well, excluding Firefox viewer for mathematical contents...). It is, however, really ugly for automatically reading / extracting the information in it.

Would it be possible that PDF generators "embed" a HTML file per PDF page?

This HTML file should be invisible, but reflect the logical structure of the PDF file. Hence PDF parsers could just extract the HTML and then apply HTML parsers (which are much simpler).

Comment: Seems to be called "structured PDF" or "Tagged PDF" according to https://youtu.be/KmP7pbcAl-8

Comment: You can add tags but PDF generators are not required to do so.

Comment: This is a structured PDF, which is a necessity for a properly accessible document. You might look out for accessible PDF or PDF/UA and according tools.

Comment: @MaxWyss What does "UA" stand for?

Comment: @MartinThoma: quoted: PDF/UA (PDF/Universal Accessibility) is the informal name for ISO 14289, the International Standard for accessible PDF technology.